# Reverse for-loop - explanation wanted

Tags: java, string, reverse

I've been programing in java for a while now but I'm just getting back to the basics and try to actually understand what is going on.

The syntax for reversing a string using a for-loop that decrements instead of incrementing is

```
for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

But I don't really understand why I have to put " - 1 " after .length()? Here's my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    reverseVertical("laptop");
}

private static void reverseVertical(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
    }

}
```

What is the logic behind the " - 1 "? I can't make any sense of it - other than it actually works.

Comment: Indices are zero-based! The _first_ character in the stirng has index `0`, but the _last_ has index `length-1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a string has 4 characters, you'll get the first one via `charAt(0)`, and the last one via `charAt(3)`, because the index is zero based. So your loop would start at 3 and ends at 0, and not start at 4.

Comment: Of course! That makes a lot of sense. Lovely answer!

Answer (score 3):

You have to start at `length - 1` because Strings, like many other Java Lists and Arrays are *0-indexed*. This means their indexes go from 0 to `capacity - 1`.

Attempting to read the position at `capacity` will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that `String` objects are backed by a `char[]`.  So iterating over a string follows the rules for any other Java array, where `.length()` is the size (count, capacity) of the array.  Indexing into any array (including strings) is 0 based, so the item in the "first" slot is accessed using 0 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays begin with index 0 up to n-1 if the allocated size was n.
To prevent an IndexOutOfBoundException the correct (highest) valid index is n-1. 
However array.lenght will return n. So you have to shift the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string "Test" the the total length is 4, but the charatcter counts starts from 0 and ends at 3 and if you have string length in your loop as string.length(), it would 4 but it ends at 3.

So here your loop will start at 3 and will end at 0.
so to avoid the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` have it goes as string.length()-1